# SSH MySQL 'admin'@'localhost' ERROR 1045 (28000)

Tags: mysql, privilege

I was unintentionally remove all privilege for user 'admin'@'localhost', now I totally cannot access mysal database with shell command, it show the error as:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I've tried

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '*8E10D9A5B6AB6F50F9FBBAAAD1C3A2F7AA885CVV' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

but still no luck!

can anyone please help to resolve this problem?

Comment: Bit confused about the question you mention. Could you describe a bit more. Example how you are trying to connect ? Is it first you connect to the server by ssh and then trying mysql -u username -p ? Second can  you access the mysql using root ?

Comment: @Abhik Chakraborty, I can access mysql by logged on as root, however, all database with user 'admin' cannot be access after full privileges are removed.

Comment: hmm can u check something.. login as root, the do as -  use mysql ; then use this SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user; and see what u see for admin user

Comment: it returned `ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user 'admin'@'localhost' for table 'user'`

Comment: no no login as root and then try above u should not get that error if u login as root

Comment: Password:
[root@UNIX-001 ~]# mysql -u admin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow`

mysql> SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;
ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user 'admin'@'localhost' for table 'user'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47452/discussion-between-abhik-chakraborty-and-conmen)